# Iterate values based upon some Number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 arrays:

```
var sku = ["SCC2GROS", " MKL7P5SV", " MKL7P5EB", " OXL4CWL", " OXL4CWXXS"];
var quantity = ["1", "10", "8", "1", "2"];
var price=  ["68.00", "25.00", "25.00", "165.00", "165.00"];
```

I want to iterate the values of sku and price array based upon quantity. i.e. for SCC2GROS quantity is 1 It will print one time with the price. But for MKL7P5SV and its price will print 10 times. I am trying the nested loop

```
for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
    
for(var j=0; j< q[i]; j++){
    console.log(s[i][j] +" " + q[j] + " " + p[j]);
    
    
}
```

}

But it's not the type of output I need. Is there anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there.

In order to loop on the sku array you need to get the array [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length). The loop is:

```
for(var i=0; i<sku.length; i++) {
```

Because you need to print so many times the sku and price elements you need to get the corresponding quantity [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and loop like:

```
for (var j = 0; j < quantity[i]; j++) {
```

The snippet:

```js
var storeArr = [];

var sku = ["SCC2GROS", " MKL7P5SV", " MKL7P5EB", " OXL4CWL", " OXL4CWXXS"];
var quantity = ["1", "10", "8", "1", "2"];
var price=  ["68.00", "25.00", "25.00", "165.00", "165.00"];
for(var i=0; i<sku.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < quantity[i]; j++) {
        var str = sku[i].trim() + " " + price[i];
        storeArr.push(str);
        console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great. I don't understand what I am missing

Comment: why we use trim?

Comment: can I store the full output in the array and later access outside of the loop?

Comment: @AsmaAhmad Snippet updated, now you have a storeArr

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a nested loop. Use a plain loop and use the index when referencing all arrays.

```js
var sku = ["SCC2GROS", " MKL7P5SV", " MKL7P5EB", " OXL4CWL", " OXL4CWXXS"];
var quantity = ["1", "10", "8", "1", "2"];
var price=  ["68.00", "25.00", "25.00", "165.00", "165.00"];

for (let i = 0; i < sku.length; i++) {
  console.log(sku[i], quantity[i], price[i]);
}
```

If you also need the total price, use the `*` operator to multiply.

```js
var sku = ["SCC2GROS", " MKL7P5SV", " MKL7P5EB", " OXL4CWL", " OXL4CWXXS"];
var quantity = ["1", "10", "8", "1", "2"];
var price=  ["68.00", "25.00", "25.00", "165.00", "165.00"];

for (let i = 0; i < sku.length; i++) {
  console.log(sku[i], quantity[i] * price[i]);
}
```

Comment: it's not a required output

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: in the first step, the program identifies the quantity, and in the second step values (sku and price) print according to that number

Comment: Ok, so multiply using the multiplication operator?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use .repeat(integer) to log more than one.

This is my solution, i hope that is helpful

```
const sku = ["SCC2GROS", " MKL7P5SV", " MKL7P5EB", " OXL4CWL", " OXL4CWXXS"];
const quantity = ["1", "10", "8", "1", "2"];
const price=  ["68.00", "25.00", "25.00", "165.00", "165.00"];


sku.forEach(
  (item, index) => {
    const str = `SKU : ${item.trim()} - PRICE : ${price[index]}  `;
    console.log(str.repeat(+quantity[index]));
  }
);
```